# php regular expression matching log file

Tags: regex, preg-match

I am trying to match exception lines I see in a log file. The log file has the format of
"[timestamp] threadid(8 alphanumeric digits) applicationName(any length of alphanumeric characters) E(to denote exception message)"

So a sample log exception message would be:

"[11/27/12 22:33:02:635 EST] 0000009a myApplication E " Anything can come after the E.

I am having trouble finding a regular expression to match this using PHP preg_match

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
'/^\[[^\]]+\]\s\w{8}\s[^\s]+\sE.*/m'
```

The trailing "m" ensures, that the wedge at the beginning matches the beginning of a line in your log.

This solution will of course only work, if all the log entries look pretty similar except for the "E". If there are log entries e.g. without timestamps, it might fail and you have to look for more detailed expressions like sputnick's.

Comment: That works pretty well except it doesn't match the strings with more than 1 space before and after the 'E' for example:
"[3/21/13 13:43:59:396 CDT] 00000075 myApplication   E   "

Can someone help with that? I am trying to modify '/^\[[^\]]+\] \w{8} [^ ]+ E.*/m' to work with it but I can't

Comment: Try this:
'/^\[[^\]]+\]\s\w{8}\s[^\s]+\s+E\s+.*/m'

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex (with *capturing group*):

```
/^\[\d+/\d+/\d+\s+\d+:\d+:\d+:\d+\s+\w+\]\s+\w{8}\s+\w+\s+E(.*)/
```